# multiple checkbox in powershell GUI

Tags: powershell

I have a GUI that runs various tasks.
One task I can't seem to resolve is how to handle multiple checkbox conditions, and a condition statement depending on what is ticked or not.

Sample code as follows

edit: formatting on code doesn't seem to work for me.....

```
    If ($Checkbox1.Checked)
 {
    Write-Host "Only checkbox 1 is checked"
 }
ElseIf ($Checkbox2.Checked)
 {
    Write-Host "Only checkbox 2 is checked"
 }
ElseIf ($Checkbox3.Checked)
 {
    Write-Host "only checkbox 3 is checked"
 }
Elseif ($Checkbox1.Checked -And $Checkbox2.Checked)
 {
    Write-Host "Both Checkbox1 and Checkbox2 are checked"
 } 
Elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked -And $Checkbox3.Checked)
 {
    Write-Host "Both Checkbox2 and Checkbox3 are checked"
 } 
Elseif ($Checkbox1.Checked -And $Checkbox2.Checked -And $Checkbox3.Checked)
 {
    Write-Host "All are checked!"
 } 
Else
 {
     Write-Host "No checkbox selected"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to create a numeric value (bitmap aka 'flags') where each bit represents a checkbox.
This is easy using the `-shl` (ShiftLeft) operator:

```
[int]$Checkbox1.Checked        --> 0 or 1
[int]$Checkbox2.Checked -shl 1 --> 0 or 2
[int]$Checkbox3.Checked -shl 2 --> 0 or 4
```

Next perform a switch on the possible combinations of these values.

```
# combine the numeric values for the checkboxes
$binValue = [int]$Checkbox1.Checked -bor 
           ([int]$Checkbox2.Checked -shl 1) -bor 
           ([int]$Checkbox3.Checked -shl 2)

# check what value the above returned
switch ($binValue) {
    0 { Write-Host "No checkbox selected"; break }
    1 { Write-Host "Only checkbox 1 is checked"; break }
    2 { Write-Host "Only checkbox 2 is checked"; break }
    3 { Write-Host "Both Checkbox1 and Checkbox2 are checked"; break }
    4 { Write-Host "Only checkbox 3 is checked"; break }
    5 { Write-Host "Both Checkbox1 and Checkbox3 are checked"; break }
    6 { Write-Host "Both Checkbox2 and Checkbox3 are checked"; break }
    7 {  Write-Host "All are checked!" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this...

```
Clear-Host
[void][system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
        
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$objForm.Text          = 'Test'
$objForm.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,200)
$objForm.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$CheckedListBox              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$CheckedListBox.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,20)
$CheckedListBox.size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,100) 
$CheckedListBox.CheckOnClick = $true 
$CheckedListBox.Items.AddRange(1..3)
$CheckedListBox.ClearSelected()

$objForm.Controls.Add($CheckedListBox)

$CheckedListBox.Add_Click({
    For ($i=1;$i -lt $CheckedListBox.Items.count;$i++) 
    {$CheckedListBox}
})

# put form in front of other windows
$objForm.TopMost = $True

# display the form
$DisplayForm     = $objForm.ShowDialog()

ForEach ($CheckedItem in $CheckedListBox.CheckedItems -join ',')
{
    Switch ($CheckedItem)
    {
        1       {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        2       {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        3       {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        {1,2}   {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        {1,3}   {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        {2,3}   {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        {1..3}  {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
    }
}
```

To keep this simple, I did not obc=viously add buttons, so just click what you want a close the form with the 'X' to see the results of your selection.